# Trying to modify display of my url for html index page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

What I would like to do is serve up a file such as "index.html" and have the url read mysite.com/boat-repair/electrical-system-repair.

I tried putting the target file in a series of sub directories hoping the directory names would show in the address bar,but that still just pulls up the target file and does not change the address bar. I see this all the time but I just can not seem to find the resources I need to figure it out.
I tried this as an experiment:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule    ^boat-repair/?$    boat-repair-electrical-system-repair.html
```

and when I typed in mysite.com/boat-repair.html it just displayed a test html page I have named boat-repair.html, did not change the url and did not load the boat-repair-electrical-system-repair.html page.

Clearly I am missing something here, can someone please point me in the right direction. I have been researching this for many hours and clearly still do not have a clue on how to accomplish my goal.

Comment: The URL you typed in the browser doesn't match the pattern you used in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Michael .. thank you for the clue... though more detail would have been helpful it got me thinking about how the rule is supposed to work.

This is the working code I came up with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/?$    /boat-repair/electrical-system-repair  [NC]
RewriteRule    ^boat-repair/electrical-system-repair/?$    /index.html [NC]
```

The first rule tells the server to serve up: boat-repair/electrical-system-repair when the root directory is entered.

The second rule tells the server if the pattern: boat-repair/electrical-system-repair is matched to serve up index.html

The file served up (index.html) in the last step can named anything you like as it will load, but not show in the address bar.

So after both rules are implemented you get: http://yoursitename.com/boat-repair/electrical-system-repair/ in the address bar, now I just need to figure out a way to remove the trailing slash.

These rules of course get put in the htaccess file.

In order for this to work you must have the folders named in the rules even if they are just dummy folders. If dummy folders be sure to put a text document in each folder named "DO NOT DELETE THIS FOLDER" so that six months down the road you do not look at these empty folders and delete them!

I hope this helps someone else trying to implement this on their site.

Answer (score -2):

you may have already tried this but...is your server self hosted if so rest/reboot the server this might work because it may not be showing the file on the HDD instead the file loaded to the ram